# How to Register Widget with Post thumbnail and post title

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

[image: post thumbnail]

I want to register a sidebar like this. I have register a widget with this code

```
register_sidebar(array(
            'name'=>esc_html__('Main Sidebar', 'software'),
            'id'=>'sidebar-1',
            'description'=>'This widget is for Right Sidebar',
            'before_widget'=>'<aside class="col-sm-3 right-part pr0">',
            'after_widget'=>' </aside>',
            'before_title'=>'<div class="col-sm-12"><h2>',
            'after_title'=>'</h2></div>'
            ));
```

My html codes are

```
<aside class="col-sm-3 right-part pr0">
<div class="col-sm-12 sms p0">
    <img src="images/sms-add.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Recommended</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 apps p0">
    <div class="col-sm-3 mb-img recommended p0">
        <img src="images/window.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 recommended pr0">
        <h4>Windows 7 mainstrem support ends</h4>
    </div>
</div></aside>
```

So How can I do this. DO I need to register a custom widget? or there are any other solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can also make your custom but follow this plugin it will so

https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-posts-widget/

so from both of this you get output that you want.

**WITH OUT PLUGIN **

**STEP -1**

In your functions.php file, write the following code:

```
<?php 
class Realty_Widget extends WP_Widget{
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'realty_widget', // Base ID
        'Realty Widget', // Name
        array('description' => __( 'Displays your latest listings. Outputs the post thumbnail, title and date per listing'))
       );
}
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['numberOfListings'] = strip_tags($new_instance['numberOfListings']);
        return $instance;
}


} //end class Realty_Widget
register_widget('Realty_Widget');
```

**STEP -2 The form() method**

very simple form with 2 fields: a text field for the Widget title, and a drop down list for the number of listings we want to show:

```
<?php function form($instance) {
    if( $instance) {
        $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
        $numberOfListings = esc_attr($instance['numberOfListings']);
    } else {
        $title = '';
        $numberOfListings = '';
    }
    ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title', 'realty_widget'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('numberOfListings'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Listings:', 'realty_widget'); ?></label>
        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('numberOfListings'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('numberOfListings'); ?>">
            <?php for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++): ?>
            <option <?php echo $x == $numberOfListings ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="<?php echo $x;?>"><?php echo $x; ?></option>
            <?php endfor;?>
        </select>
        </p>
    <?php
    }
```

**STEP - 3 The widget() method**

```
<?php 
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    $numberOfListings = $instance['numberOfListings'];
    echo $before_widget;
    if ( $title ) {
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    }
    $this->getRealtyListings($numberOfListings);
    echo $after_widget;
}
```

**STEP -4 Pull our Custom Posts**

This method will do a query of our custom posts. It will only return the number of posts that we’ve saved in our widget. Add this code to our class:

```
<?php 
function getRealtyListings($numberOfListings) { //html
    global $post;
    add_image_size( 'realty_widget_size', 85, 45, false );
    $listings = new WP_Query();
    $listings->query('post_type=listings&posts_per_page=' . $numberOfListings );
    if($listings->found_posts > 0) {
        echo '<ul class="realty_widget">';
            while ($listings->have_posts()) {
                $listings->the_post();
                $image = (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'realty_widget_size') : '<div class="noThumb"></div>';
                $listItem = '<li>' . $image;
                $listItem .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                $listItem .= get_the_title() . '</a>';
                $listItem .= '<span>Added ' . get_the_date() . '</span></li>';
                echo $listItem;
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }else{
        echo '<p style="padding:25px;">No listing found</p>';
    }
}
```

note here in above 4th step my post type is listing so i used it

you can set your own post type.

ex- you need to use like this

```
$listings->query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=' . $numberOfListings );
```

AND IN END once you get image and text then set your own css as per your design.

Comment: Thanks. But Manually How can I add this without plugin?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.